# How to get a badge in-line on the right side inside a Bootstrap dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu like this:

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Action
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Foo <span class="badge pull-right">63</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bar <span class="badge pull-right">12</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get a "badge" counter on the right side for each of the items, but somehow it always jumps to the next line. I assume that's because the dropdown "li" > "a" items are block items. When I don't use the pull-right, it works ...but obviously I want them aligned on the right side.

Is there any easy way around that?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/392/

Comment: Your jsfiddle works fyn !

Comment: It works but the badge isn't aligned on the same line ...it jumps down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a > .badge {
    position:absolute;
    right:5px
}
```

Add `position:relative` to `.dropdown-menu > li > a`.

Remove `pull-right` class from badge.